# Parallelogram help

Tags: geometry

[image]

In a parallelogram $ABCD$, $AB=8$ $cm$, $BC=5$ $cm$, perpendicular from $A$ to $DC=3$ $cm$. Find the length of the perpendicular drawn from $B$ to $AD$.

I am not quite sure how to draw the diagram. Is this the way I should draw it?

Comment: Your picture does not quite fit the words, although it makes no difference. You should *extend* $CD$ and draw a perpendicular from $A$ meeting the extended line $CD$. But the "right" perpendicular has the ssame length as the one you drew, so it will not lead you to a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I'm sorry the picture is sideways. But it should look like this. Note we are trying to find the length of $z$.

The area is $A=3(8)=24$, but it is also $A=xz+yz$ (see why?). But we also know that $x+y=5$ and we can put this all together to get

$$A=24=xz+yz=z(x+y)=5z$$

which implies that

$$z=24/5=4.8$$

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try to express the area of parallelogram in two ways:

- using only given lengths and
- using both a given length and the length you need to find

Answer (score 0):

Based on your instruction, this is how I sketched the figure. Careful, a perpendicular line is NOT  the same thing as a diagonal. The line you drew from B to the other corner, that's a diagonal. The line you drew from D to AB is a perpendicular line (because it meets DC at 90 degrees)[image]

So from here you can't draw a perpendicular line from B that falls on AD, if you did it would have to exist above A on an extended line. Are you typed the question out correctly? If you did extend the line you could draw a perpendicular line from B but I'm not sure that's what they want you to do here :/

[image]